# How to have async function inside subscribe ts angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have an input box that on valueChange calls an async function that calls API.

```
    this.searchFrom = new FormGroup({
      ss: new FormControl()
    });
    this.searchFrom.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((b) => {
        this.search(b);
      });
```

```
  search(ss: string) {
    console.log(" API");
    this.http.post(endpoint + 'search', { 'ss': ss })
      .toPromise()
      .then((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log("✅✅");
      });
  }
```

It just calls function, it doesn't calls `.then` 
In console.log I get only:

```
>  API
```

Comment: Is there any error you got ?

Comment: No, I didn't get any error.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: In developer console, network tag your request finished or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about rxjs and it operators.

Here a working solution:

```
this.searchFrom = new FormGroup({
    ss: new FormControl()
});

this.searchFrom.valueChanges
.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(x => this.search(x.ss))
).subscribe((result) => {
    // result contains HTTP-result if non Error
});


search(ss: string) {
    console.log(" API");
    return this.http.post(endpoint + 'search', { 'ss': ss });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are converting your observable into promise, anyway i have another approach to solve your problem,

Try this

```
 this.searchFrom.valueChanges.pipe(
            map(value => value.ss),
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap(search => this.search(search))
 ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));

 search(ss: string) {
  return this.http.post(endpoint + 'search', { 'ss': ss })
 }
```

Comment: You need a map operator as well right which is missing in your solution.

Comment: the map is needed but to get the value of the formControl : map(value => value.ss)

Comment: this.searchFrom.valueChanges on subscription will return a event object I believe, so to fetch the string entered we need to use the map operator

Comment: Yes gerome you are right, il update my map operator